# Extracting data files for different dates from database table

Tags: oracle11g

I am on windows and on Oracle 11.0.2
I have a table **TEMP_TRANSACTION** consisting of transactions for 6 months or so. Each record has a transaction date and other data with it.

Now I want to do the following:
1. Extract data from the table for each transaction date
2. Create a flat file with a name of the transaction date;
3. Output the data for this transaction date to the flat file;
4. Move on to the next date and then do the steps 1-3 again.

I create a simple sql script to spool the data out for a transaction date and it works. Now I want to put this in a loop or something like that so that it iterates for each transaction date.

I know this is asking for something from scratch but I need pointers on how to proceed.

I have Powershell, Java at hand and no access to Unix.

Please help!

Edit: Removed powershell as my primary goal is to get it out from Oracle (PL/SQL) and if not then explore Powershell OR Java.

-Abhi

Comment: You could check http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/04/use-oracle-odp-net-and-powershell-to-simplify-data-access.aspx, it's a very good article about Powershell and Oracle.

Comment: Show us what you already have in PL/SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve what I was looking for. Below are the steps (may be not the most efficient ones, but it did work :) )

1. Created a SQL script which spools the data I was looking for (for a single day).

set colsep '|'

column spoolname new_val spoolname;

```
select 'TRANSACTION_' || substr(&1,0,8) ||'.txt' spoolname from dual;

set echo off

set feedback off

set linesize 5000

set pagesize 0

set sqlprompt ''

set trimspool on

set headsep off

set verify off

spool &spoolname

Select
''||local_timestamp|| ''||'|'||Field1|| ''||'|'||field2
from << transaction_table >>
where local_timestamp = &1;

select 'XX|'|| count(1)
from <<source_table>>
where local_timestamp = &1;

spool off

exit
```

2. I created a file named content.txt where I populated the local timestamp values (i.e. the transaction date time-stamps as

   `20141007000000
   20140515000000
   20140515000000`
3. Finally I used a loop on powershell which picked up one value from content.txt and then called the sql script (from step 1) and passed the parameter:

`PS C:\TEMP\data> $content = Get-Content C:\TEMP\content.txt`

```
PS C:\TEMP\data> foreach ($line in $content){sqlplus user/password '@C:\temp\ExtractData.sql' $line}
```

And that is it!

I still have to refine few things but at least the idea of splitting the data is working :)

Hope this helps others who are looking for similar thing.